# Equivalente de chmod en Windows

Tags: windows, powershell

En **Windows** ¿cual es el equivalente de `chmod` de **Linux**?

O si hay algun modo de utilizarlo.

Comment: Creo que lo que quiere es ICACLS.  Puede usar attrib para hacer el archivo read-only o sistema.

Comment: Parece ser que este es el comando. Gracias

Comment: @Duston podrías decirlo en una respuesta así marca la pregunta cómo respondida.

Comment: que version de windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que lo que quiere es ICACLS. Puede usar attrib para hacer el archivo read-only o sistema.  Ayuda para ICALCS: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls  Ayuda para ATTRIB: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/attrib